# Finding the linear mapping/transformation of a given polynomial w/ matrix given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$B_1$ = {${1+x,1-x,1+x^2}$} and $B_2$ = {${1+2x,x,1+x+x^2}$} are bases for $P_2(\Bbb R)$. Suppose $T \in L(P_2(\Bbb R))$ (the set of linear mappings on $P_2(\Bbb R)$(?)) and the matrix representing $T$ with respect to $B_1$ and $B_2$ is

$M(T,B_1,B_2)$ = $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Determine $T(1-x+3x^2)$.

---

Using a bit of reverse engineering I deduced this from the columns on the matrix:

$[T(1+x)]_{B_2} = 1(1+2x) + 0(x) + 1(1+x+x^2)$

$\implies T(1+x)= x^2+3x+2$

$[T(1-x)]_{B_2} = 1(1+2x) + 2(x) + 1(1+x+x^2)$

$\implies T(1-x)= x^2+5x+2$

$[T(1+x^2)]_{B_2} = 0(1+2x) + 1(x) - 1(1+x+x^2)$

$\implies T(1+x^2)= -x^2-1$

However there doesn't seem to be any kind of pattern I can use to figure out what T actually does, so I'm not sure how to determine $T(1-x+3x^2)$. This could be glaringly obvious but I'm still really new to this stuff so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B_1$ is a basis, you can find (unique) $a,b,c$ such that

$$ 1 - x + 3x^2 = a \cdot (1 + x) + b \cdot (1 - x) + c \cdot (1 + x^2). $$

For example, by comparing the coefficient of $x^2$ on both sides, we see that $c = 3$. I'll leave finding $a,b$ to you. Then, using the linearity of $T$ we have

$$ T(1 - x + 3x^2) = a T(1 + x) + b T(1 - x) + c T(1 + x^2). $$

Comment: Thanks mate huge help!

Answer (score 1):

$B_1=\{1+x,1-x,1+x^2\}$ is a basis

You have to find components of $\vec p=1 - x + 3x^2 $ in terms of elements of $B_1$

$\alpha (1 + x) + \beta  (1 - x) +\gamma (1 + x^2)\equiv 1 - x + 3x^2$

Expanding and reordering

$\alpha +\beta +\gamma + x (\alpha-\beta)+\gamma x^2\equiv  1 - x + 3x^2$

which lead to the system

$\alpha +\beta +\gamma =1;\;\alpha-\beta=-1;\;\gamma=3$

$\vec p=\left(-\dfrac{3}{2}, -\frac{1}{2},3\right)$

Apply matrix $T$ to the vector $\vec p$

$T \vec p=(-2, 2, -5)$

and you have the image with the scalar product of $(-2, 2, -5)$ with the element of $B_2$

$(-2, 2, -5)\cdot (1+2x,x,1+x+x^2) = -7 - 7 x - 5 x^2$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that!